# ¿Cómo procesar un webhook usando PHP?

Tags: php, webhook

Una plataforma externa envía una notificación a la URL que yo indiqué cuando hay un cambio en su sistema. Necesito recoger esa notificación y actuar en consecuencia.

La única información que me proporciona el proveedor del servicio es la siguiente:

> A push notification will be sent to this URL when a new booking, significant booking modification which effects availability or cancellation occurs. The bookid and status are appended to your url like this example. `yoururl.com/yourpage?bookid=12345678&status=new`
>
> Your server should return an HTTP 200 header to acknowledge receipt of the notify. If there is no response or a response HTTP code of 400 or higher the notify will be retried after a delay.

Tengo un servidor Apache con PHP montado y debo procesar la notificación desde ahí. Y no sé cómo abordar el problema.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. Imagino que para ello habrás configurado un *webhook* en dicha plataforma, ¿no es así? ¿Qué has hecho o intentado del SDK de dicha plataforma? Si nos das más información (como el nombre de la plataforma que envía la petición) como el método (POST, GET, PUT, en JSON, XML, etc) nos facilitarás la tarea de ayudarte.

Comment: Si no aportas más información tendré que votar el cierre de la pregunta por no estar claro lo que preguntas. Deberías aportar más información tal y como te la solicitamos y, sobre todo, indicar qué has probado o qué SDK o documentación te facilita el proveedor. PD: Lo que deseas recibir es un [*webhook*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) que no tiene nada que ver con una [*notificación push*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnolog%C3%ADa_push#Notificaci%C3%B3n_push).

Comment: Hola Oscar, gracias por tu modificación. El caso es que lo que dice la documentación de la plataforma externa es: 

"A push notification will be sent to [la url que yo indique]",,, "Your server should return an HTTP 200 header to acknowledge receipt of the notify. If there is no response or a response HTTP code of 400 or higher the notify will be retried after a delay. "

Y por el otro lado, yo dispongo de un servidor Apache con PHP para procesar esa notificación.

No se como procesar esa notificación... no se si viene información en el _POST, _GET...
Espero haber aclarado la pregunta

Comment: No, no lo has aclarado, aunque por el contexto se parece mucho al funcionamiento de los webhooks. ¿Qué servicio es el que quieres usar? Quizá sí me lo dices puedo buscar en su documentación o ayuda el tipo de comunicación que usa (aunque todo apunta a webhook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu proveedor va a cargar el script PHP que le proporciones enviando parámetros HTTP a través del método `GET`, por lo que deberás hacer uso de la variable súper global `$_GET` para acceder a ellos:

```
<?php
/* Leemos los datos proporcionados en los parámetros GET */
$datos = [
  'bookid' => $_GET['bookid'],
  'status' => $_GET['status'],
];
/* Guardamos la información en un archivo de registro */
file_put_contents(
  'registro.log',
  json_encode($datos) . PHP_EOL,
  FILE_APPEND
);
```

Si el script se llama `webhook.php` y la URL base es `https://pepito.com` habrá que configurar como *webhook* la URL `https://pepito.com/webhook.php` y esperar la llegada de una notificación.

Al llegar una notificación el script PHP creará un archivo llamado `registro.log`, o agregará los datos al final de él si ya existe, con los datos en JSON de la llamada recibida.

Comment: Muchas gracias Oscar, desconocía la existencia de "WeebHook". Voy a probar con la solución que dices y a esperar a que llegue alguna notificación. En cuanto obtenga algún resultado marcaré tu respuesta como "solución".

Comment: Cuando proporciones más información de la plataforma que estás usando y que te manda notificaciones házmelo saber para agregarlo a tu pregunta y enriquecerla, así mejorará la puntuación que ha obtenido (por ahora negativa).

Comment: ¿Pudiste probarlo?

Comment: Hace 15 minutos llegó la primera notificación! pero al final no llegó nada en JSON. Todo llegó en el $_GET. Aún así muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Seguimos sin saber qué página, servicio o algo para saber qué tipo de comunicación hay. A ciegas es difícil saber qué te manda el servidor.

Comment: Bueno, es un Channel Manager cuya única información es la siguiente:

Comment: Esta es la info (pensé que se trataba de una "push notification" y andaba perdido hasta que me dijiste que se trataba de un WebHook):

A push notification will be sent to this URL when a new booking, significant booking modification which effects availability or cancellation occurs.
The bookid and status are appended to your url like this example.
https://yoururl.com/yourpage?bookid=12345678&status=new
Your server should return an HTTP 200 header to acknowledge receipt of the notify.
If there is no response or a response HTTP code of 400 or higher the notify will be retried after a delay

Comment: Sólo agregando eso a la pregunta no se te hubiera cerrado por no estar claro lo que preguntas. Con esa información queda completamente claro cómo te envía el servidor la información (obviamente por parámetros `GET`). Editaré tu pregunta para agregar está información, editaré mi respuesta y propondré la reapertura.

Answer (score 0):

Al no conocer cómo llegaban los datos usé este código para verificar todas las posibilidades:

```
$msg = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). "\n\n";

$msg .= "_POST:\n";
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $msg .= var_export($_POST, true);
}
$msg .= "\n";

$msg .= "_GET:\n";
if(!empty($_GET)){
    $msg .= var_export($_GET, true);
}
$msg .= "\n";

$msg .= "_PUT:\n";
if(!empty($_PUT)){
    $msg .= var_export($_PUT, true);
}
$msg .= "\n";

$bruto = '';
try {
    $bruto = file_get_contents('php://input');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $bruto = 'VACIO';
}

$msg .= "php://input (bruto):\n";
if(!empty($bruto)){
    $msg .= var_export($bruto, true);
}
$msg .= "\n";

mail("xxx@xx.com","Información recibida", $msg);
```